# Different YAxis scaling for LineChart with multiple data sets (more than 2)

Tags: java, scale, mpandroidchart, android-graphview

I need a chart with multiple lines, and each of this line needs to have its own YAxis so it could scale to the full size of rgaph view. I know how to implement this with MP Chart if I have two data sets. But I need draw on graph up to 16 different data sets with its own YAxises. Any suggestion with code example please?

[image: MP Chart with 2 YAxises and multiple data sets]